# How do I read and replace specifc value in one column of the text files?

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have around 70000 text files in a folder that contain a table comprised of 5 columns e.g:

```
7   0.1   0.2     0.007    0.000077
7   0.6   0.8888  0.9      0.07
3   0.8   0.09999 0.87     0.6544444
1   0.0009 0.09   0.999    0.777777
6   0.2    0.333  0.222    0.33333
```

I'd like to replace the number "7" in the first column with the "5". To do this I wrote the following code to read the text files in the folder and changes 7 to 5 in the entire text file.

**My question is how do I apply this to only column one instead of the entire text file?**

```
import glob
for filepath in glob.iglob('path to folder/*.txt', recursive=True):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        s = file.read()
    s = s.replace('7', '5')
    with open(filepath, "w") as file:
        file.write(s)
```

Comment: I had a similar task, I remember using sed or awk bash commands. You could take a look at those also or s = s.replace('7', '5', 1)

Comment: your code replaces all the `7` in the text file. you should use `csv` and use delimiter as tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) has a convenient `inplace` keyword argument.

```py
from fileinput import input as fileinput
import glob

with fileinput(files=glob.iglob('path to folder/*.txt', recursive=True), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        if fields[0] == '7':
            line = '\t'.join(['5'] + fields[1:])
        print(line, end='')
```

Perhaps try without `inplace=True` until you have convinced yourself that this works correctly.

I have simply assumed your columns are tab-delimited; it should not be too hard to adapt this to space-delimited or to simply use a different delimiter like comma etc.  (If your input is proper CSV, perhaps use Python's `csv` module instead.)

I have also assumed that you only want to change `7` to `5` and not also e.g. `777` to `555`.  If you wanted that, perhaps simply

```py
    # ...
    fields[0] = fields[0].replace('7', '5')
    line = '\t'.join(fields)
    # ...
```

If your columns are separated by unpredictable amounts of whitespace but the field length does not change when you replace (like here, where you replace a single character with a single character), you can use

```py
    fields = line.split()
    fields[0] = fields[0].replace('7', '5')
    line = fields[0] + line[len(fields[0]):]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `list` comprehension and slicing and `str.replace`:

```
import glob
for filepath in glob.iglob('path to folder/*.txt', recursive=True):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        s = '\n'.join(['\t'.join([v.replace('7', '5') if i == 0 else v for i, v in enumerate(i.split('\t'))]).rstrip() for i in file])
    with open(filepath, "w") as file:
        file.write(s)
```

Comment: you can simply use `[... for i in file]`

Comment: @deadshot You're right, edited my answer.

Comment: instead of using index you should try split like `i.split()[0].replace('7', '5')`

Comment: @deadshot Split won't work because when I one to add it back to a string I wouldn't know how many spaces to put in.

Comment: Your code does not (any longer?) use `splitlines`. I have a hard time figuring out if the indices are correct, even after trying to work this out for a while. Perhaps you could explain your reasoning about the hard-coded `4`?  You are assuming that's the width of the first column and that every instance of `7` in that column should be replaced?

Comment: @tripleee Edited mine.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand your reasoning, and suspect a beginner would not stand a chance. Now you are assuming that the second character in the second column will always be a dot, is that right?

Comment: @tripleee Yeah maybe my answer is a bit bad... yours is better +1, let the OP decide

Comment: You can `split` and `replace` and then just use the length of the new value to decide how many characters to replace at the beginning of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your files are using some kind of delimiters, like a comma or a tab. In which case you could read the file using the CSV module and use the appropriate delimiter in the argument for `csv.reader` function call.

Once you do that you can get values in a column-wise manner and get around to updating only one column at a time.

A sample code snippet to reading a tab separated file would be as follows:

```
with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    rows = csv.reader(file, delimiter="\t")
```

*Note the delimiter keyword argument*

The variable *rows* hold values for each row and you can select a column for a row using list indices as the variable *rows* is a nested list.